Cast nested arrays to nested slices
I am struggling to cast a nested array, say of type [5][5]u8, to the corresponding nested slice type like [][]u8.
I have a function which accepts a nested slice:
fn func(arg: [][]u8) void {...}

I have a variable of nested arrays:
var a = [_][5]u8{[_]u8{1} ** 5} ** 5;

I want to pass a to func. I tried the following approaches but they do not work:
func(a[0..])
func(a[0..][0..])

How can I properly cast to nested slice from nested array?

Such a cast is not possible.
You would have to allocate memory for the outer slice in some way. For example, using the stack:
const std = @import("std");

pub fn main() !void {
    var arr = [_][5]u8{[_]u8{1} ** 5} ** 5;

    var outer_slice_memory: [5][]u8 = undefined;
    for (&arr, 0..) |*sub, i| {
        outer_slice_memory[i] = sub[0..];
    }

    foo(&outer_slice_memory);
}

fn foo(slices: [][]u8) void {
    std.log.info("{any}", .{ slices });
}

This prints:
info: { { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 } }

Note, the lifetimes: outer_slice_memory becomes invalid after main exists.
Explanation
An array of arrays like [5][5]u8 is just 25 consecutive bytes in memory.
But a slice consists of two fields: a many-item pointer plus length. Something like this: struct { ptr: [*]T, len: usize }. So, a slice of slices would contain a many-item pointer to memory with other slices.
In other words, an array of arrays and a slice of slices have very different memory representations. So a direct cast is not possible.
Prefer const inputs when possible
Note that if foo doesn't need to change the input data, then the slices should be declared const, this would allow for a convenient way to create temporary slices, which is especially convenient in tests:
fn foo(slices: []const []const u64) u64 {
    var max: u64 = 0;
    for (slices) |subslice| {
        for (subslice) |value| {
            max = @max(max, value);
        }
    }
    return max;
}

test foo {
    try std.testing.expectEqual(11, foo(&.{
        &.{ 1, 2, 3, 4 },
        &.{ 5, 6 },
        &.{ 7, 8, 9 },
        &.{ 10, 11 },
    }));
}


Yep this is helpful! Thanks. Athough now I am thinking about some comptime function which converts arbitrary nested array to nested slice.
